# Android : set TextView style at runtime

Tags: android

Does any body know how to set style for `TextView` at run time:

something like this

```
myTextView.setStyle(R.style.mystyle);
```

Answer (score 25):

Very easy just use setTextApparence and your style

```
 myTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.boldText);
```

Comment: is there something similar for a linearLayout?

Comment: Just a quick note that `setTextAppearance(Context context, @StyleRes int resId)` is deprecated and we should use `setTextAppearance(@StyleRes int resId)` instead

Answer (score 3):

you will have to manually set each element of the style that you change, there is no way to setStyle at run time, AFAIK.

```
myTextView.setTextAppearance
myTextView.setTextSize
myTextView.setTextColor
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but if i want i want to add more than star check box dynamically. it seems that there is know way to set style at run time.  but in my case i want to add this star checkbox

<CheckBox   style="?android:attr/starStyle" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"   /> 

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

I also still did not find (sadly) a way to change Style at runtime.

If it is just about changing the checkbox appearance (as you mention in a comment of another answer), you can use this:

```
myCheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.star_checkbox);
```

And have a star_checkbox.xml file in the drawable directory describing the checkbox background according to its states such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_checkbox_checked_focused" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_not_checked_focused" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_not_checked" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" />
</selector>
```

Also you need the corresponding png files in you drawable directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying myself to do a similar thing.

My reason is that I want to use a style from my own Theme,  BUT  my User Interface Layout is entirely generated in code( using a custom layout builder), without defining any widgets in XML.  So I cannot  set a style in the XML layout of my widget – there isn’t any XML layout.

I  am thinking that I will be able to set this style in the code  of my widget  by using

TypedArray a =

context.obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet
 set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)

Here it seems (to me) that

1. AttributeSet set = null; because this is what the XML inflater would have provided.
2. int[] attrs  = R.styleable.MyWidget;  defines what attributes I want to look at.
3. int defStyleAttr = myWidgetStyle; which is a reference, defined in my Theme, to a style for MyWidget.   These are both defined in XML files in res/values.
   “myWidgetStyle” follows the pattern of name the android developers have used in their code.
4. defStyleRes = 0;  I am hoping that I don’t need to think about this.

Then  to  get any property , such as a background  color,

Color  color = a.getColor(R.styleable.MyWidget_background,  R.color.my_default);

a.recycle();

This does seem to work –so far anyway.

It seems that  the android build system conveniently  generates the correct index to use in a.getColor, and names it R.styleable.MyWidget_background .  I didn’t make this name myself so  Android must have done it using my  XML for my styleable  MyWidget.

I expect one can look up the correct index by searching  the TypedArray for the required attribute , but that would be inefficient and the TypedArray looks like an unpleasant contraption to deal with. I would  use a very long stick to poke it!

Don

Answer (score 0):

TextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)

Although there is construction available but it seems its buggy, I tried this and found specified style won't apply on my view.

After searching further got this filed bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12683

To workaround this issue I am using setBackgroundResource, setTextAppearance, etc methods dramatically :)