# android : Textview Set Style in runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android : set textView style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237752/android-set-textview-style-at-runtime)

i just wanna know how i can implement style in runtime i saw some posts here but i couldnt find anything properly

i create a new Textview , like this

```
TextView title = TextView(this, null, R.style.TitleSep);
```

this its my style xml.

```
 <style name="TitleSep">
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
         <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffff0000</item>
         <item name="android:padding">2dip</item>
    </style>
```

Nothing change at all, i saw the api and should be change the style instead i got the default style.

Any advice.

Cheers 
Ron

Comment: its not the same question, in that question they set some attributes, when i create the object i pass the style but doesnt work! cheers

Comment: i think u pass the attribute set as null.this is a problem

Comment: Pinki what do u meant with set as null this could be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the layout file, do the following - it's simpler.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/TitleSep"
    android:text="hello" />
```

UPDATE: (from comment)

Why don't create the textview at compile time, but make it invisible, and set it to visible if and when you need to show it. The reason I suggest this roundabout method is because setting the style at compile time seems simpler.

Comment: Ron asking it in runtime only

Comment: I cant do that, because i got data from the service and this data tells me if i have to create the textview. Cheers m8

Comment: Why don't create the textview at compile time, but make it invisible, and set it to visible if and when you need to show it. The reason I suggest this roundabout method is because setting the style at compile time seems simpler.

Comment: Thanks Rajath DSouza, im looking to invisible textView

Comment: Great. If you found it useful, please help restore my points by upvoting this answer and/or accepting it :D

Comment: can u edit the answer, because that its wrong, i'll do it just change u answer please

Answer (score 8):

You can define the TextView in separated layout file (like Rajath DSouza suggested). And then load the view from layout file (inflate it) dynamically. 
For example:

```
TextView title = (TextView) activity.getViewInflate().inflate(R.layout.styled_textview, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks i will check it, at the moment i try to make all my textview invisible and if the data cames i set to visible, thanks